# How do I make markdown.js display a markdown document as HTML in a TWebBrowser in Delphi?

Tags: delphi, markdown

How do I make markdown.js display a markdown document as HTML in a TWebBrowser in Delphi?

Given the contents of a string containing Markdown, how do I get markdown.js to convert that markdown into HTML, and display that HTML in a TWebBrowser component, all inside my Delphi desktop application?

**UPDATE:**

Following Wouter's example (thank you, Wouter!), if I simply do this:

```
procedure TForm2.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  WebBrowser1.Navigate('file://C:/junk/markdown/lib/markdown.js');
end;
```

Then I get a series of warnings.  First, from Windows "protecting" me from the javascript. I approve and run everything, but finally I get:

[image]

Comment: Which bit are you struggling with? Do you know how to invoke Javascript from Delphi.

Comment: Are you looking for a solution to work with some JavaScript or just looking for converting Markdown to HTML? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9850876/open-source-markdown-processor

Comment: To be sure, do you want to edit Markdown in a TMemo for example, and then display the formatted result in a TWebBrowser?

Comment: Actually, yes, I just want to preview markdown.

Comment: Ah, I that clears things up. You navigate to the Javascript file. Instead, create a .html file with the HTML that I have in my post, and make sure that markdown.js is in a subfolder called `lib` (subfolder from where the HTML is)

Comment: Doh!  What a doofus.  I should have seen that.  I even made the markdown.html file myself.  ;-)

Comment: Perfect -- thanks so much.  I appreciate the help. Javascript/TWebBrowser are fairly new to me, and I'm grateful.  Now on to losing the dependency on the external files. ;-)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

OK, this works:

[image: Screenshot]

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head><style>body{font-family:Arial;font-size:small}</style></head>
<body>  
    <div id="markdown"></div>
    <input type="hidden" id="hidden" /> 
    <script type="text/javascript">
        hiddenEl=document.getElementById('hidden');
        markdownEl=document.getElementById('markdown');
    </script>
    <script src="lib/markdown.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Delphi code:

```
procedure TForm38.Memo1Change(Sender: TObject);
begin
  WebBrowser1.OleObject.Document.GetElementByID('hidden').setAttribute('value', Memo1.Text);
  WebBrowser1.OleObject.Document.ParentWindow.execScript('markdownEl.innerHTML = markdown.toHTML(hiddenEl.value)');
end;

procedure TForm38.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  WebBrowser1.Navigate('file://c:/!/markdown.html');
end;
```

Of course this is just a proof of concept. 
Especially the Delphi code should check if the document was loaded, but that type of code would only be distracting for this example.

---

Maybe you're wondering why I first write the contents of the TMemo to a hidden element?
That's because it's complicated to pass a text with linebreaks to a JavaScript function when you build the JavaScript as a string. You would get something like this:

```
window.alert("Hello
World");
```

---

**update**
In my example, I have markdown.js in a subfolder `lib` of the html file. 
Make sure that `<script src="lib/markdown.js"></script>` really points to the location of Markdown.js

Comment: Oh my, Wouter, that looks perfect.  Thanks so much.  This is so close -- but I get a ton of warnings and I can't load the markdown.js in the FormCreate.  I get a series of warnings and error messages, and finally a javascript error in Markdown, claiming "window is undefined.

Comment: That worked!  Thanks so much.  One little caveat:  The *.exe needs to be in the same directory as the HTML file.  Delphi XE3 puts it in a subdirectory by default.

Comment: Not especially.. I had my html and js under c:\!\, while my exe was somewhere under c:\users\wouter\. It also works when they're on a web server somewhere.. Maybe you're using some relative paths somewhere?

Comment: Anyway, good to hear that you've got it to work. Markdown is quite nice. It lets users do simple markup without any tools or buttons, and it's much easier to explain to non-technical people than HTML, which can be a big plus. What are you using it for?

Comment: I'm writing an editor specifically for use with LeanPub for use in writing my Delphi book -- and for other LeanPub writers, of course.  Thanks so much -- you really got me on my way.