# How can I do custom markdown rendering using ShowDown.js?

Tags: css, markdown, javascript, showdown

Thanks to my fine StackOverflow friends, I have a great answer for [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13301935/2044).

So I have a great preview working -- ShowDown.js was the markdown parser I ended up using.

So my question now is this:  do you all know of anyway to get ShowDown to render to my specifications using, say, CSS?

For instance, the way ShowDown renders text marked as 'monospace' is quite small, and I'd like to be able to manually adjust the size of the monospace tag.

If I can't, are there any other rendering engines I might try that do allow you to customize the rendering output?

Thanks.

Comment: What is the current output? (Is ShowDown.js actually generating CSS or just raw HTML?)

Comment: Sorry --  Current output is raw HTML as far as I know.  I'll double check that, though.

Comment: If there's no CSS in the auto-generated HTML, then why wouldn't you just slightly hack the generated HTML to refer to a style?

Comment: Warren -- I suppose that is what I'll have to do.  Looks quite scary, though!  ;-)